# Screen scraping JS page

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I'm trying to scrape this page http://www.buddytv.com/trivia/game-of-thrones-trivia.aspx and it's not working.

I tried

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load_file($url);
```

But for the question I'm looking to grab (.trivia-question) can't be found. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot!

And I tried

```
  <?php
  $Page = file_get_contents('http://www.buddytv.com/trivia/game-of-thrones-trivia.aspx');
  $dom_document = new DOMDocument();
  //errors suppress because it is throwing errors due to mismatched html tags
  @$dom_document->loadHTML($Page);
  $dom_xpath_admin = new DOMXpath($dom_document_admin);
  $elements = $dom_xpath->query('//*[@id="id60questionText"]');
  var_dump($elements);
```

Comment: i dont see *.trivia-question* class in html

Comment: <div id="id60questionText" class="trivia-question" style=" ">In the season 3 finale, who did Samwell and Gilly ran into when they crossed the Wall? </div>

Comment: ok, but when you do view source you wont see it, because it's being rendered by javascript, you only see it in your debugger, right?

Comment: I'm guess that's the issue, yes. But there is gotta be a way to grab the content of a page after its JS was rendered, right ?

Comment: Yes there is, use http://phantomjs.org/ ;)

Comment: I'm really bad at JS, any other options ?

Comment: It's not that hard let me write you an example

Comment: @metareviewr you can learn c# or java.

Comment: @Prix  Ha, thanks but I really meant "an easier option"

Comment: @metareviewr in c# it would be about 5 lines or less to get it ;) but then again if you don't know c# at all it wouldn't be as easy.

Comment: Guess I need to learn some new languages...

Comment: @metareviewr and btw the trivia is there search for: `var oCurrentQuestionResponse` in JSON format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok then here is phantomjs example:

You need to download phantomjs from: http://phantomjs.org/,  put somewhere where you can easily access by a script.

Test it by running {installationdir}/bin/phantomjs (phantomjs.exe on windows) --version

Then create JS file somewhere in your project, ex browser.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.buddytv.com/trivia/game-of-thrones-trivia.aspx', function() {

page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {

    search = page.evaluate(function() { 
        return  $('#id60questionText').text();
    });

    console.log(search);

    phantom.exit()
  });
})
```

Then in your PHP script read it like:

```
$pathToPhatomJs = '/home/aurimas/Downloads/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs';

$pathToJsScript = '/home/aurimas/Downloads/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-x86_64/browser.js';

$stdOut = exec(sprintf('%s %s', $pathToPhatomJs,  $pathToJsScript), $out);

echo $stdOut;
```

Change `$pathToPhatomJs` and `$pathToJsScript` according to your configuration.

If you are on windows this may not work. You can then change PHP script to:

```
$pathToPhatomJs = '/home/aurimas/Downloads/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs';

$pathToJsScript = '/home/aurimas/Downloads/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-x86_64/browser.js';

exec(sprintf('%s %s > phatom.txt', $pathToPhatomJs,  $pathToJsScript), $out);

$fileContents = file_get_contents('phatom.txt');

echo $fileContents;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'm gonna try to make sense f it

Comment: I'm unfortunately on Windows so I'm having issues with the last part.

Comment: what's going wrong?, can you send me how you are implemented it? use http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I'm just going to run it locally. So on wamp I tried adding a folder with phantom and the php file and the code is http://pastebin.com/SJ19pQqK but the var is empty.

Comment: Your paths is wrong `$pathToPhatomJs` and `$pathToJsScript` first should be full path to phantomjs executable in your case phatomjs.exe and second full path to js file, not relative.

Comment: When I am using above script then O/P is  `[object Object]` how to get data from this?