# Automatically provide response to HTML form server-side using PHP

Tags: php, phpquery

I am building an app that extracts data from a website and displays them in my app. I am using PHPQuery to extract data in my server-side code.

However, one page contains an .asp form with two dropdown menus. I need to select an option in both of them and then parse the resulting html. I need to do this server-side, so javascript doesn't seem to be the option.

How can I do so? Can it be done using PHPQuery or some other technology is required?

The page in question is: http://www.bput.ac.in/exam_schedule_ALL.asp

Comment: Have no answer, but will downvote. Right?

Comment: My guess is the down vote was for lack of any code - you didn't show what you have already tried to solve the issue.

Comment: Because I didn't find anything that would solve the issue. I need a starting point. Even Google search yielded nothing.

Comment: That's fair enough. I'm not saying the down vote was justified. Personally, I think it's valid question.

Comment: you get my upvote, some people are only arround to downvote, because i was fishing for simialer and would like to hear others input or opinion regarding it.

Comment: You're asking for opinions about which library to use which is a no-no.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448439/screen-scraping-js-page

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326301/make-a-javascript-aware-crawler

Comment: There isn't really much to go on here. You've got a page that you access by submitting a form. You just need to figure out what sort of request the form is making (i.e. what fields/values, what URL, and what method) and reproduce that request.

Comment: @ShantanuPaul Please check my answer below and see if I've got the gist of what you're looking for without having to dive into other technologies.  No idea why it was downvoted within 1 second of being posted.  Not even I can read that fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using PHP and phpQuery, I suggest you also try cURL.

Explore what the form submits via JavaScript and replicate that via cURL.  Do this to get the format of the posted (assumption) data, which you can then replicate in a cURL request to the same endpoints.  JavaScript won't be necessary, and you can get the same results you need.  In this case, you won't need the item mentioned next.

Alternatively, if you have a browser, such as webkit, phantomJS, etc, you can write an automation script to run those steps and return the results, depending on exactly what you need returned.  See more complete examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17449757/573688 for how others suggest you do this.  **NOTE** this is not usually necessary if you just need to emulate POST requests.

This is a non-coded answer because it's not entirely clear what direction helps you the most.

Comment: I'm impressed, how do you get a -1 immediately after posting?

Comment: I have added a url to a page which I need to process in the question. Please look at it and if possible provide any specific solution.

Comment: Hi @ShantanuPaul If you open your network tab on chrome or firefox, you can see the post parameters and response.  If you use cURL in php to send a post, and capture the response, you can build up the details for each possible combination, by simply iterating through all the first dropdown and second dropdown combinations.  Explore cURL in more detail using PHP, and you'll see how to put this together.

Answer (score 0):

1. On page works JavaScript, which should make an AJAX request to the server and pass the selected value from both SELECT.
2. The server receives the AJAX request, performs the request to the correct address (you can use phpQuery) and prints the response (gets to the response on AJAX request).
3. JavaScript on the page receives a response to an AJAX request and performs actions affected.

Comment: The question is asking how to make the request from the server. i.e. How do you do step 2 of this answer.

Comment: The main part of the question is "I need to select an option in both of them and then parse the resulting html.", which you aren't addressing at all.

Comment: How do you send the ajax request programatically, i.e. without a user having to select the option?