# Using GET curl PHP to display Javascript value

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm trying to scrape a website using PHP curl. I want to get the Javascript value of a GET response in a site. My code goes as follows:

Function to get the string:

```
function GetStr($string, $start, $end) // getting the string
{
  $str = explode($start, $string);
  $str = explode($end, $str[1]);
  return $str[0];
}
```

And My PHP curl :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'the site I want to scrape');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

echo $result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $nonce = trim(strip_tags(GetStr($result ,'id="woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce" name="woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce" value="','"'))); //getting the nonce value of a javascript which is in ','.
```

Somehow I tried to echo `$result` and the website showed up but not the javascript value. Am I missing something or Am I doing it wrong? Also, the Get response in that site has a cookie in it so do I need to put that cookie add an header?

Output:
There's no output I tried to `echo $nonce;` when using the curl.
If I echo `$result`, The output would be the website's page since it's a GET response page from a site.

Additional info:
Again, my goal is to get the website's javascript value, the GET Response has of that site has:

```
<input type="hidden" id="woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce" name="woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce" value="8d39be8bdc" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/checkout/" />  </div>
```

And I want to capture it with my code above but it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Please post the curl output here as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen scraping JS page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448439/screen-scraping-js-page)

Comment: Is there any other way without downloading other sources? I dont want to mess up with another application and also want a pure scraping through PHP curl. Is it possible or I'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you save the output to `$result` and passing `$saitama` to the function

Comment: Sorry about that Alon, I changed some variables and I forgot to change that one. Still have the same problem though even with the correct variables inserted.

Comment: You must understand that cURL is fetching a static string (The source  of the page) and not executing any JS code that is embedded in the page. If the page you are trying to scrape is depending on some javascript code that is running on that page then you must use another method to scape that will allow you the get the rendered page after the document has finished executing the javascript code, and phantomJS does just that - It allow you to scape the page as if it was accessed from a browser

Comment: Now it really clears everything. Thank you.